# Java 8 String outofmemory error

Tags: java, xml, memory, out-of-memory

I have a big XML file that I am parsing using SAX parser. During the processing I create a big HashMap having key and values for parsed JSON.

As per my understanding, in java 8 you dont need to set any Permgen setting while running java application, it creates Strings in Heap but some how I am still getting OutOfMemoryError. Is my understanding right or I am choosing a wrong parser?

Comment: pls add more details. your heap size, the size of the data and where in the code do you think the OOM is coming.

Comment: String were always stored in the heap, in Java 8 the MetaSpace replaced the PermGenSpace but that rarely matters : PermGenSpace was used to store class declarations, and while I'm not very knowledgeable about MetaSpace I'm pretty sure you rarely have to tweak it

Comment: Hi Aaron and Abhishek, thanks for the response. I thought string were part of runtime constant pool which is similar to heap but not exactly. What else do you think, I should try?

Comment: Also, do you think if it matters to look into what GC I will be using?

Comment: I guess you're referring to the `String` literal pool. Most probably in your SAX handler, you would be creating objects rather than literals. Again, it's all speculation without any details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look into the following -

1. Which garbage collection you are using.
2. If you are using IDE, check if you are using correct java version. Sometimes you IDEs can have setting to run on specific JVM.

Which java installation you are using, BTW?